# How to plot longitude and latitude on 2D map unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I've recently been playing around in unity trying to get a 2D map to get going with coordinates, so I need longitude and latitude. However, the problem I'm facing is that they are getting placed everywhere in my unity world when passing in the coordinates, is there a way to clamp it so the coordinates will stay within the dimensions of the map image that I have?